# Best Practice Guide: Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, ui-guidelines

Does anybody know Swing related GUI guidelines - specifically on how to design Swing apps and which components I should use? I'm not looking for an official standard, but pragmatic tips I can use to set a good standard for my projects.

I haven't used too much of Swing by myself. Surely clicking a GUI with a GUI designer isn't a big deal. However I'd like to get some insights from people who have experience with Swing and know what to avoid. Swing lately (in Java 6- 10) got decent changes. So there isn't too much specific standardization out there currently.

Answer (score 6):

There are many resources out there discussing good uses of Swing or showcasing good uses of Swing.  Here are a few:

- [Kirill Grouchnikov's Blog](http://www.java.net/blogs/kirillcool)
- [Pushing Pixels](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/)
- [Swing FX](http://swing-fx.blogspot.com/) (hasn't been updated in a while, but has lots of good stuff in the archives)

These resources aren't simple best practices lists, but I find that I'm constantly inspired by general design blogs and Swing design blogs in particular.  On top of that, projects like [swinglabs](https://swinglabs.dev.java.net/) can show you what people can and are doing with Swing.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to select the right layout manager for placing components in a panel I tend to take a quick look through Sun's [visual guide to layout managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).